# How to find the Xpath of the element as per the html through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

[image: I want to click on cross using Selenium]

Tried something like this in python unable I want to click on cross using Selenium.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@onclick, 'parent.$WZRK_WR.closeIframe('60005','intentPreview');')]").click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the element depicted as **X**, first you need to induce *WebDriverWait* while switching to the `<iframe>` and again induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='wiz-iframe-intent']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='CT_Interstitial']//span[@class='CT_InterstitialClose']"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: `wiz-iframe-intent` is that visible in screen shot shared by OP ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Of-coarse the frameID is pretty much visible.

Comment: Ok. from my end in that screen shot it is not visible.

Comment: @cruisepandey Perhaps as a community member you, me and everyone are seeing the same screenshot :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open below URL and Click on Add to Chrome button.

Xpath Helper- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en

2. Once plugin added to Chrome. Open your application/webpage and press SHIFT+CTRL+X. Black window will appear on top then you can play with xpath.

If xpath is invalid- then you will get xpath error and if no matches found then it will display NULL.

Note- To check element attribute still you can use F12 that is nothing but default inspect element for all browser then check attribute and create your own xpath and try.

**Xpath Syntax**
/`/ tagname[@attribute-name=’value1′]`  and if you are not sure about tag name then no worry you can try with * also

```
//*[@attribute-name='value1']
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with an iframe. Follow below steps :

1. You'll need to switch control to iframe.
2. Then perform your action (in this case 'Click close').
3. Switch the control back to default frame.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this `xPath`:

```
//div[@id = 'contentDiv']/div/div/span[@class = 'CT_InterstitialClose']
```

***Code:***

```
close_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'contentDiv']/div/div/span[@class = 'CT_InterstitialClose']")))
close_btn.click()
```

***Imports:***

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

***Explanation:***

`WebDriverWait` is used to wait until element will be clickable, and only then clicks on it. In this example `WebDriverWait` will wait at least 10 seconds until element will be clickable.

***PS:*** as I see in the screenshot your element is probably in `iframe`. That means you have to switch to this `iframe` first, to be able to interact with the elements in it. The code sample for it would be like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "XPATH_TO_FRAME")))
# do stuff
close_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'contentDiv']/div/div/span[@class = 'CT_InterstitialClose']")))
close_btn.click()
# switch back to default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this **css_selector** :

```
div.CT_InterstitialContents+span.CT_InterstitialClose[onclick]
```

**Xpath** would be :

```
//div[@class='CT_InterstitialContents']/following-sibling::span[@class='CT_InterstitialClose' and onclick]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write xpath using class name of span. Please refer an example below.

```
//span[@class='amountCharged']
```