# How to send text to the Email field using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

[image]

Hi tried something like it was working before

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/input").send_keys("abhishek.gupta1608@toppr.in")
```

but now it gives error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="inputs"]//input[@name="email"]"}
```

Comment: Can you share the URL ?

Comment: https://eu1.dashboard.clevertap.com/login.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with name :

```
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("abhishek.gupta1608@toppr.in")
```

in case you want to introduce webDriverWait :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'email'))).send_keys("abhishek.gupta1608@toppr.in")
```

Note that you will have to imports these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**UPDATE1:**

You are in iframe , you will have to switch the focus of your web driver to default content and then you can interact with it:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'email'))).send_keys("abhishek.gupta1608@toppr.in")
```

Comment: Thanks but getting TimeoutException

Comment: Well , Are you handling the advertisement pop up?

Comment: Yes I am handling advertisement popup

Comment: Becaue I do not have full code for handling the advertisement pop up , So I am clicking on cross button manually , and then the code provide by me works well.

Comment: Can you share the code for handling the pop up , I will inject that with my current code.

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='wiz-iframe-intent']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='CT_Interstitial']//span[@class='CT_InterstitialClose']"))).click()

Comment: @AbhishekGupta : Update the code in update1 section in my answer , Please get the code from there.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta : If the given name is unique , you should always prefer that. Not css selector or xpath.

Answer (score 1):

To send a character sequence to the **Email** field you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']"))).send_keys("abhishek.gupta1608@toppr.in")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("abhishek.gupta1608@toppr.in")
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi Debanjan I am getting Timeout Exception as I am logging in after handing advertisement popup as answered by you  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590374/how-to-find-the-xpath-of-the-element-as-per-the-html-through-selenium-and-python#51591441