# how to get xpath of href title attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How to extract xpath of this (title=" I want to get this item")

```
<div class="ads__item__actions">
<a href="https://www.xxx.html" title="I want to get this item" class="ads__item__ad--title" 
xpath="1">
some text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Depends on the language you are using. This question here has an answer for users of Python >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590374/how-to-find-the-xpath-of-the-element-as-per-the-html-through-selenium-and-python

Comment: Where's the closing tag for the first `div`?

Comment: the closing tag is </div> @jackFleeting

Comment: I understand, but where is it located - before the `<a>` tag or after?

Comment: after <a> tag it at the end of the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the (corrected) html snippet in your question, then

```
 titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/a')
 print(titles[0].get_attribute('title'))
```

should output:

```
I want to get this item
```